# Cannot mount large .img disk image files

Tags: mount, disk-image

Normally, when I open a .img disk image (with Disk Image Mounter, which right-click menu tells me), I can mount it and browse the disk image. However, with large disk images (over a gigabyte, this has happened with more than one image), I get the following error:
[image: screenshot of error]

Does anybody know why this happens, if this is a bug, and how to fix it?

Also, someone suggested that ulimit might be at fault. Here's the output of `ulimit -a`:

```
hitechcomputergeek@hitechcomputergeek-Latitude-2120:~$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15905
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15905
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

However, I no longer believe that ulimit is at fault, as I tried running nautilus as root and I still got the same error message.